# NGINX based sample website in a container

Tags: nginx, docker

I am using Docker and tried to use James Turnbull's book to create a container with a working nginx. After creating and running container I have tried to access `HTML` page on the public port, but I've got `403 Forbidden` status code.
`Dockerfile` is here:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get -yqq update && apt-get -yqq install nginx

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/website
ADD nginx/global.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
ADD nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

EXPOSE 80
```

`global.conf`:

```
server {
        listen          0.0.0.0:80;
        server_name     _;

        root            /var/www/html/website;
        index           index.html index.htm;

        access_log      /var/log/nginx/default_access.log;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/default_error.log;
}
```

`nginx.conf`:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
daemon off;

events {  }

http {
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

I have used above command to run new container:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 80 --name website -v $PWD/website:/var/www/html/website:rw user007/website nginx
```

Comment: What's in the access log?

Comment: `docker logs` output is also empty for this container.

Comment: And which URL did you use? Can you try with curl?

Comment: @AdrianMouat: You can check it here: http://159.203.13.18:32774

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the nginx user just doesn't have read permissions for the files. The easiest way to solve this is to run `chmod -R a+r` on the volume. Be aware this will allow any user to read the files.

In addition, the nginx user will need to have `execute` permissions on all the parent directories.

Comment: `-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  121 Oct 31 16:00 index.html`
I have already tried similar things, but same error.

Comment: What is the host os? Also, the nginx user needs access to the parent dir. Try going into the container and seeing if you can cd to the dir and cat the file as the nginx user.

Comment: Got to say I don't like the files being owned by root. That might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you verify that the port forwarding is running properly?(That mean is the error is from host os)

maybe.. you need to edited your command.

`sudo docker run -d -p 80` >> `sudo docker run -d -p 80:80`

Comment: It is running on a random public port. Problem was with privileges.

Answer (score 0):

> It cause by SELinux.
>
> Using Volumes with Docker can Cause Problems with SELinux.
>
> See this [link](http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/06/using-volumes-with-docker-can-cause-problems-with-selinux/) for the full story.
>
> When using SELinux for controlling processes within a container, you need to make sure any content that gets volume mounted into the container is readable, and potentially writable, depending on the use case.

You can temporarily issue by running:

```
su -c "setenforce 0"
```

> This got easier recently since Docker finally merged a patch in docker >1.7
>
> This patch adds support for "z" and "Z" as options on the volume mounts (-v).
>
> For example:

```
docker run -d -p 80 --name website -v $PWD/website:/var/www/html/website:z user007/website nginx
```

Will automatically do the

```
chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /var/db
```